# Docker: could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm new to docker and working on dockerising an existing RoR app.
Here's my `docker-compose.yml` file:-

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
```

On running `docker-compose up`, I'm able to map to the rails server but getting the error in the title, looks like postgres is not connecting to the container.
I don't know what to do, I just want to my machine to the rails app in docker conatiner.

Comment: In your `database.yml` file, you need to set the database host name to the name of the database container, `postgres`.  `localhost` refers to the Rails application container itself.

Comment: You change `postgres: image: postgres:latest` to `db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: myapp_db
    env_file:
      - .db.env
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"`